# How to pass String into ListView - Android

Tags: android, listview

I have made an `ListView` with `items`, `qty`, `rate` and retrieved the data from MySQL but I need to add even my "Service Charges" and "Net Amount" to the `ListView` but I have "Service Charges" and "Net Amount" in the variable not in the MYSQL how can I insert this two into the `ListView`.

Here is my code:

```
public void getPostedJobsLocal(){

    String url=Config.GET_PAYMENT_BILL;
    String url1= local_job_id;
    String URL=url+url1;
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            showJSONPosted(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSONPosted(String response) {
    ParseJSONPayBillLocal pj = new ParseJSONPayBillLocal(response);
    pj.parseJSONPayBillLocal();
    CustomListPayBillLocal cl = new CustomListPayBillLocal(this, ParseJSONPayBillLocal.items, ParseJSONPayBillLocal.qty,ParseJSONPayBillLocal.rate);
    lview.setAdapter(cl);
}
```

So how can insert the "Service Charges" and "Net Amount" which I have as variable into the `ListView`?

Comment: float service_charges[] and new_amount[] pass to listview

Comment: i cant get you.

Comment: you can define seperate variable for your service charges and net amount  and passes that to your adapter Constructor

Comment: @Anjali if i do like that ,it says Strings can not be passed.

Comment: @iamRaja Are items, qty, rate Strings arrays?

Comment: because your have to update your Adapter class for the same

Comment: @KNeerajLal for time being i made it as String.

Comment: @KNeerajLal Any idea.?

Comment: @iamRaja Check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its more of a hack. You can add the items to the String arrays before giving it to the Adapter.

Something like this,

```
private void showJSONPosted(String response) {
    ParseJSONPayBillLocal pj = new ParseJSONPayBillLocal(response);
    pj.parseJSONPayBillLocal();

    ParseJSONPayBillLocal.items = append(ParseJSONPayBillLocal.items, "Service Charges");
    ParseJSONPayBillLocal.qty = append(ParseJSONPayBillLocal.qty, "your_qty");
    ParseJSONPayBillLocal.rate = append(ParseJSONPayBillLocal.rate, "your_rate");

    ParseJSONPayBillLocal.items = append(ParseJSONPayBillLocal.items, "Net Amount");
    ParseJSONPayBillLocal.qty = append(ParseJSONPayBillLocal.qty, "your_qty");
    ParseJSONPayBillLocal.rate = append(ParseJSONPayBillLocal.rate, "your_rate");

    CustomListPayBillLocal cl = new CustomListPayBillLocal(this, ParseJSONPayBillLocal.items, ParseJSONPayBillLocal.qty, ParseJSONPayBillLocal.rate);
    lview.setAdapter(cl);
}

public static <T> T[] append(T[] arr, T element) {
    final int N = arr.length;
    arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, N + 1);
    arr[N] = element;
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: it gives "Method call required".

Comment: it give this error "   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3"  for the Line "ParseJSONPayBillLocal.items[ParseJSONPayBillLocal.items.length] = "Service Charges";
"

Comment: Increase the size of the arrays by 2.

Comment: What is the length of arrays now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123427/discussion-between-iamraja-and-k-neeraj-lal).

Comment: @K Neeraj Lal  im using for loop for the idexing:                                 
            for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++){
                JSONObject jo = users.getJSONObject(i);
                items[i] = jo.getString(ITEMS);
                qty[i] = jo.getString(QTY);
                rate[i] = jo.getString(RATE);

            }

Answer (score 1):

Make a model class containing **Service Charges** and **Net Amount**

```
public class MyModel {

    String serviceCharges;
    String netAmount;


    public MyModel (String serviceCharges, String netAmount){
        this.serviceCharges= serviceCharges;
        this.netAmount= netAmount;

    }

    public String getServiceCharges() {
        return serviceCharges;
    }

    public void setServiceCharges(String serviceCharges) {
        this.serviceCharges= serviceCharges;
    }

    public String getNetAmount() {
        return netAmount;
    }

    public void setNetAmount(String netAmount) {
        this.netAmount= netAmount;
    }
}
```

Now you can create an ArrayList of MyModel class and add your services charges and net amount values:

```
ArrayList<MyModel> myModelArray = new ArrayList<MyModel>();
myModelArray.add(new MyModel("serviceCharge1","netAmount1"));
myModelArray.add(new MyModel("serviceCharge2","netAmount2"));
.......
.......
```

Now you can pass this **myModelArray** to your list adapter for binding data with the list view.

Retrieve values by:

```
myModelArray.get(position).getServiceCharges();
myModelArray.get(position). getNetAmount();
```

Note: Shift to retrofit, it is 4 times faster than volley.